# Expo crashes after start

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, expo

I got an issue when starting my React Native project using `expo start`.
The browser opens up and shows me the following page:
[image: Expo Browser]

After about a second the page goes dark completely and the following error appears in the console (with `EXPO_DEBUG=true` set):

```
Expo DevTools is running at http://localhost:19002
Opening DevTools in the browser... (press shift-d to disable)
error Invalid regular expression: /(.*\\__fixtures__\\.*|node_modules[\\\]react[\\\]dist[\\\].*|website\\node_modules\\.*|heapCapture\\bundle\.js|.*\\__tests__\\.*)$/: Unterminated character class. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.

Metro Bundler process exited with code 1
Error: Metro Bundler process exited with code 1
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\@expo\xdl@56.2.8\src\Project.ts:1804:16)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:300:26)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:210:5)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:272:12)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

I'm running Windows 10 1903 x64, NodeJs v12.11.0 and the following dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
  "expo": "^35.0.0",
  "react": "16.8.3",
  "react-dom": "16.8.3",
  "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-35.0.0.tar.gz",
  "react-native-web": "^0.11.7"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "@types/react": "^16.8.23",
  "@types/react-native": "^0.57.65",
  "babel-preset-expo": "^7.0.0",
  "typescript": "^3.4.5"
}
```

Any idea what to do now?

Comment: Are the statements executed within the project folder?

Answer (score 12):

**just need to change some hashes on your project:
Go to :**
*\node_modules\metro-config\src\defaults\blacklist.js*

```js
var sharedBlacklist = [
  /node_modules[/\\]react[/\\]dist[/\\].*/,
  /website\/node_modules\/.*/,
  /heapCapture\/bundle\.js/,
  /.*\/__tests__\/.*/
];
```

**to this :**

```js
var sharedBlacklist = [
  /node_modules[\/\\]react[\/\\]dist[\/\\].*/,
  /website\/node_modules\/.*/,
  /heapCapture\/bundle\.js/,
  /.*\/__tests__\/.*/
];
```

Answer (score 3):

I was running Windows 10 with Node LTS version v10.16.3 and it was working fine.
I changed to Node Current Version v12.11.0 and I got the same error.
Reverted back to Node LTS version v10.16.3 and it is all working fine again.

I also upgraded the Expo cli to from 3.1.2. to 3.2.3.
Just in case I reverted to the earlier version again (it is only 12 days old)
npm -g i expo-cli@3.1.2.

You can try that as well if changing your Node version doesn't work.

After the above changes, everything is working smoothly again.

Comment: Downgrade from Node 12 to 10 solved my Windows 10 error, thanks and upvote

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall latest Node version

And reinstall Node Version 10.16.3

It should work.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue too after updating NodeJS to 12.13. 
I downgraded to 10.17 and it's working back again.